# How to round 7.97708892975923E+15?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Console Application which gets a string from another program.
The string is: 79.77088691596279
Now I want to convert it to a double with Convert.ToDouble() and it returns 7.97708892975923E+15.
The next step is rounding it to 2 digits, but it fails (returns also 7.97708892975923E+15) because of the E+15.
How could I manage to round this easily?
This is my example code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("79.77088691596279"); // 79.77088691596279
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("79.77088691596279")); // 7,97708869159628E+15
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("79.77088691596279"), 2)); // 7,97708869159628E+15
```

Comment: It is working, I didn't see any problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your machine is interpreting the . as a thousands separator rather than a decimal point.

Have you tried specifying the InvariantCulture when converting to double:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble("79.77088691596279", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that on your machine comma is the decimal seperator instead of dot.

Try using the string `"79,77088691596279"` instead.

This is evident because 79.77088691596279 gets converted to 7977088691596279 in your case, so . is the "thousand separator" in your culture and is ignored by `Convert.ToDouble`.

This is evident because `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("79.77088691596279"));` output 7,97708869159628E+15 on your machine, and here you can see that is uses comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: Or add CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as a parameter to the Convert method, this will get you "." for decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
// with 2 decimal places
Console.WriteLine("79.77088691596279".ToString("N2")); 
// with none decimal places
Console.WriteLine("79.77088691596279".ToString("N0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 7,97708869159628E+15
```

Note that E+15 means nothing more than [number in front]*10^15. So your computer actually tells you he sees *79.77088691596279* as *7977088691596279* (note no "." here). So yes, your computer sees the "." as a thousands operator instead of a decimal operator.

Try using a "," as told in several answers already and post results. The following indeed fixes this:

```
Convert.ToDouble(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double d = 79.77088691596279;
 Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}",d);
```

OR

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}",Convert.ToDouble("79.77088691596279"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Math.Round(...)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zy06z30k(v=VS.90).aspx